# r- Rename multiple columns by extracting part of the name

Tags: r, gsub, strsplit

I´m an R beginner and perhaps someone should have asked this already, but i couldn't find an answer.

My data look like this.

```
id_lance <-c("300_09_11", "400_09_11", "400_09_11", "400_09_11", "500_06_08",
          "500_06_08", "500_09_11", "600_06_08" , "700_09_11", "700_09_11")

especie <-c("esp1", "esp1", "esp1", "esp2", "esp2", "esp3", "esp2", "esp3",
        "esp3", "esp4")

abundancia <-as.numeric (c("190", "267","76", "111", "34", "334", "777", "1067",
                       "19", "255"))

df = data.frame(id_lance, especie, abundancia)

matriz <-as.data.frame(tapply(df$abundancia,list(df$especie,
                                            df$id_lance),sum))

matriz[] <- lapply(matriz,function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0))
```

I want to rename columns name by extracting the first 3 numbers, i.e, "300_09_11" to "300" and so on.

I´ve been trying out with `strsplit`and `gsub` separately and then together with no success. I don´t know if it can be done with a loop or with something like this failed attempt.

```
names(matriz) <- gsub(strsplit(names(matriz), "_"),
                  paste0(substr(names(matriz)[[1]], 1, 3), names(matriz)))
```

Can anyone help me out?. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ways with `sub` and `strsplit`, but it is simple and straightforward to use `substr` here. I will also warn that naming columns with numbers is asking for trouble later on:

```
names(matriz) <- substr(names(matriz), 1, 3)
matriz
#      300 400 500 500  600 700
# esp1 190 343   0   0    0   0
# esp2   0 111  34 777    0   0
# esp3   0   0 334   0 1067  19
# esp4   0   0   0   0    0 255
```

---

A few more `base R` options for learning:

```
#with sub()
names(matriz) <- sub("_.*", "", names(matriz))

#with strsplit()
names(matriz) <- sapply(strsplit(names(matriz), "_"), '[', 1)
```

Comment: Easier that I thought.

Comment: I´m aware of the danger of using numbers as column name but I need it that way just to check my data. I´ll remove names later on for clustering analysis.

Comment: In `sapply(strsplit(names(matriz), "_"), '[', 1)`, what does the `'[', 1` mean? I'm trying to adapt this snippet for my own use but am having a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: @CelineDion Check how `letters[1]` gives `"a"` as an answer. Then try `'['(letters, 1)`

Comment: The bracket "[", is a special function that does not require the typical parentheses as most functions. But every function in R can be written with the `function(arg1, ...)` format. Try `'+'(5,4)`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

```
library(stringr)
names(matriz) = str_sub(names(matriz),0,3)
```